# How to set max size for a specific file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, logrotate

I have an application which will write to a particular log file until the user session is going on.
What i am looking for is to put a max cap on the size of a log file so it does not grow beyond a particular size, 2 scenarios which will be useful are

1. Any utility which keeps an eye on the log file and as soon as it reaches the max size start truncating the file content from the start so the application can keep appending the content at the end.
2. Any utility by which while creating the file i can specify the max size of that file and when file  reaches that maxsize it should simply not grow beyond that point.

What i don't want is

1. To set up a cron job or a script which will monitor the file size after a particular interval of time (say 1 hour)  and then delete its contents at that time.

Comment: `man logrotate`

Comment: @NiallCosgrove How to put a cap on the size of file so that it does not grow beyond a particular size ?

Comment: @Cyrus Logrotate perfoms checks for the file size every hour that is also through the cron job, i want something that will take action immediately  if file size grows beyond allocated size.

Comment: I think this question is off-topic here. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) might be a better place to ask, but `man logrotate` is the most likely answer you will get from anyone.

Comment: @NiallCosgrove Sure i will put up this question in serverfault, i  have used logrotate but in this case if i wait for logrotate to check file size after an hour, application which is writing have the potential to write huge chunks of data in short time and can potentially fill up the disk till then.

Comment: It's also possible to start your logroate job every minute with cron.

Answer (score 2):

As a shellscript:

```
file=file_to_watch
maxsize=98765
truncsice=8765
while : ; do
    inotifywait -e modify "$file"
    filesize=$(du "$file")
    if  [ $filesize -gt $maxsize ] ; then
        tail -c $truncsize "$file" > /tmp/truncatedfile.$$
        mv /tmp/truncatedfile.$$ "$file"
    fi
done
```

Note that you might get some race conditions which may lead to losing log-data.

Answer (score 1):

How about `truncate -s 10M log.txt`?

Check `man truncate` for more details

Comment: The "only" problem with a hard coded size like this is it is more than likely to cut a line anywhere, instead of removing everything up to the end of a certain line... Maybe with `truncate -s \`sed 1,10000 log.txt | wc -c\` log.txt`

Answer (score 0):

A process that removes part of a file and then let you append more data is nearly never available on any system, even though it is possible, it's just not something one does. It could be done at kernel level and be really efficient, but I've never see that either.  (i.e. the kernel would simply unlink inodes from the start of the file and have an offset in the first inode of the file for byte capability--opposed to page ability.)

On a Unix system, you can use `mmap()` and `unmap()` for that purpose. So when your app. determines that the file size went over a certain amount, it would have to read from the start of the file, determine the location of, for example, the 10,000th line of log, and then `memmove()` the rest over to the start. Finally, it would truncate the file and reopen it in append mode. This last step is a very important step...

```
// WARNING: code without any error checking
// if multiple processes may run in parallel, make sure to use a lock as well
int fd = open("/var/log/mylog.log", O_RDWR);
ssize_t size = lseek(fd.get(), 0, SEEK_END);
lseek(fd.get(), 0, SEEK_SET);
char * start = (char *)mmap(nullptr,
                            size,
                            PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
                            fd,
                            0);
char * end = start + size;
char * l10000 = start; // search line 10,000
for(int line(0); line < 10000; ++line)
{
    for(; l10000 < end && *l10000 != '\n'; ++l10000);
    if(*l10000 == '\n')
    {
        ++l10000; // skip the '\n'
    }
}
ssize_t new_size = end - l10000;
memmove(start, l10000, new_size);
truncate(fd, new_size);
close(fd);
```

(example found in [sendmail::dequeue()](https://github.com/m2osw/snapwebsites/blob/master/snapbounce/src/sendmail.cpp#L575) on GitHub which includes all the error checking not found here.)

*IMPORTANT: the `memmove()` call is going to be **slow**, especially on a rather large log file.*

Note that most of the time, when a process opens a log file, it keeps it opened and that means changing the file under its feet won't do much good. Actually, in the `mmap()` example here, you would create a gap with many zeroes (`\0` characters) between the moved data and the next write if you don't make sure to close and reopen the log (not shown in the code).

So, it's doable in code (here in C++, you could easily get that to compile in C, though.) However, if you just want to use `bash`, `logrotate` is certainly your best bet. However, by default, at least on Ubuntu, `logrotate` runs only once per day. You can change that specifically for the users who use your application or system wide.

At least you can run it hourly by moving or copying the `logrotate` script like so:

```
sudo cp /etc/cron.daily/logrotate /etc/cron.hourly/logrotate
```

You can also setup a per minute CRON file which runs that script. To edit the root `crontab` file:

```
sudo crontab -u root -e
```

Then add one line:

```
* * * * *   root    /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

Make sure to test and see that it works as expected. If you add such, you could also remove the `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` script from there so it does not try to run it twice (once on the 'daily' run and once on the per minute run.)

Just be aware that there is a lingering bug in CRON as shown in my [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cron/+bug/1779583) to Ubuntu. It can cause memory problems when using CRON too much (like once a minute).

Also, as mentioned previously with the code sample above, you must reopen the log file. Just rotating won't do you any good unless the application either reopens the log file each time it wants to write to it, or it is told to rotate (i.e. close the old file and open the new one.) Without that rotation kick, the application will continue to append data to the old file, it does not matter what it is named. Unix remembers because it uses the inode once the file was opened and not the filename. (Under MS-Windows, you won't be able to rename without first closing all accesses to the file... that's very annoying!)

In many cases, you either restart the whole app. (because it's too dumb to know how to reopen the log), you send the app. a signal so it reopens the log file, or the app. is aware that the file changed, somehow...

If the app. is not capable or knowing, restarting will be your only option. That may be *weird* for a user if it has a UI.